# NullPointerException при попытки вытащить значение из TextField javaFX

Tags: java, javafx

Я пытаюсь проверить ввод текста из полей TextField, идентификаторы им задал, но когда пытаюсь вытащить и проверить, есть ли в нём вообще данные, выдаёт ошибку. Вот код который запускается при нажатии кнопки buttonOpenOn(первый скрин) [image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Вот сам код проверки [image: введите сюда описание изображения]

А вот и сама ошибка [image: введите сюда описание изображения]

```
package com.example.banzeyprogramm;

import javafx.event.ActionEvent;
import javafx.fxml.FXML;
import javafx.scene.control.Button;
import javafx.scene.control.Label;
import javafx.scene.control.TextField;
import javafx.scene.image.ImageView;
import java.awt.Desktop;
import java.net.URI;

import java.io.IOException;



public class HelloController {

    @FXML
    private ImageView banzeyImage;

    @FXML
    private static TextField bindButton;

    @FXML
    private static TextField cpsButton;

    @FXML
    private Button discordButton;

    @FXML
    private ImageView discordImage;

    @FXML
    private ImageView menuImage;

    @FXML
    private Button offButton;

    @FXML
    private Button onButton;

    @FXML
    private Button vkBut;

    @FXML
    private ImageView vkImage;

    @FXML
    private static Label wrongText;

    @FXML
    void buttonOpenOff(ActionEvent event) {

    }

    @FXML
    void buttonOpenOn(ActionEvent event) throws IOException {
        checkWrongText();
    }

    @FXML
    void myDiscord(ActionEvent event) throws Exception{
        URI uri = new URI("https://discord.gg/ahs6Qx3fv2");
        Desktop desktop = Desktop.isDesktopSupported() ? Desktop.getDesktop() : null;
        if (desktop != null && desktop.isSupported(Desktop.Action.BROWSE)) {
            try {
                desktop.browse(uri);
            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }

    @FXML
    void myVK(ActionEvent event) throws Exception{
        URI uri = new URI("https://vk.com/daniilmuso");
        Desktop desktop = Desktop.isDesktopSupported() ? Desktop.getDesktop() : null;
        if (desktop != null && desktop.isSupported(Desktop.Action.BROWSE)) {
            try {
                desktop.browse(uri);
            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }


    private static void checkWrongText() throws IOException {
        HelloApplication newSlide = new HelloApplication();
        if (bindButton.getText().toString() != null && cpsButton.getText().toString() != null) {
            wrongText.setText("Кликер установлен");
            if (bindButton.getText().isEmpty() && bindButton.getText().isEmpty()) {
                wrongText.setText("Заполните все поля");
            } else {
                wrongText.setText("Введите корректное значение");
            }
            wrongText.setText("Кликер установлен");
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Текстом можете код приложить?

Comment: @4500zenja добавил

Comment: Ну другие у меня дела, ну занят я, ну и что — я просто попросил код для всех остальных приложить, чтобы Вашу проблему быстрее решитьт =/

Comment: У вас эти поля статичные, FX такие не инициализирует. И сам метод проверки зачем-то статичный.